# cant initialize NSTimeInterval with timeIntervalSince1970

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm trying to initialize an NSTimeInterval with this code:

```
NSTimeInterval *timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

but it keeps throwing an error:

> Initializing 'NSTimeInterval *' (aka 'double *') with an expression of incompatible type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')

How do i fix this?

Comment: read documentation of `NSTimeInterval` it is a tyoedef of double value!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSTimerInterval` is a primitive type, not an object type. No need for the pointer, just as the error states. You want:

```
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```